# Get checkin comments for changelog with merging of the Development branch to Acceptance

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have a Team Foundation Server with 3 branches on it:

- Development
- Acceptence
- Production

When we want to update our production server we first merge all changes from the Development-branch to Acceptence-branch then upload the Acceptence-branch to our Test-server. After all is tested and approved we merge the new changes from the Acceptence-branch to the Production-branch. Then upload this version to the production server.

Now for my question:

When we merge the Development-branch to the Acceptence-branch we would like to see what changes have been merged. When we check-in a new change to the Development-branch, we comment our check-in so we can see who did what. And I would like to see these comments when merging to the acceptence branch.

How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the `BuildReport` workflow activity of the [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/documentation) or 
[TFS Change Log](http://tfschangelog.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Colin Dembovsky has created a custom Build Activity that will automatically associate the original changesets (and work items!) with a CI build that would be triggered by merging into Acceptance or Production branches.

See all the details and download the binaries here: [Colins ALM Corner](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/2013/02/custom-build-task-include-merged.html)